# Is there a way to specify an OnPlatform inside of a style in the app.xaml file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code so far looks like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="smallLabelFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="12" Android="10" WinPhone="14" />

<Style x:Key="smallLabel" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource smallLabelFontSize}" />
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#999999" />
</Style>
```

Is there a way that I can set the FontSize in the style using the OnPlatform without having to reference smallLabelFontSize?

I looked here but can't see any example of how to do it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="12"/>
                <On Platform="Android" Value="10"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify OnDevice?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn Ask a new question on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This wont for for iOS